# struts action class parameters not printing in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am trying a simple struts application. And I have added few fields in action class and trying to print those fields in JSP class.

Everything is working fine and action methods are called properly except the properties are not printing on JSP page.

And also I cannot see any errors in logs.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

 <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<s:property value="test" />

</body>
</html>
```

Action class code :

```
    public class ActionClass {
    private String test="hello";
    public String execute() {

            System.out.println("hello ");
            return "success";

        }
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Add getter for your `test` property.

Comment: @AleksandrM Yes, u r absolutely right.. Its working.. thanks a lot

Comment: Or make `test` property `public`.

Comment: [`Or make test property public`](http://nooooooooooooooo.com/)

Answer (score 0):

change your code

```
public class ActionClass {
private String test="hello";
public String execute() {

        System.out.println("hello ");
        return "success";

    }
 //you can remove setter.
 public void setTest(String test)
 {
   this.test = test; 
 }
 public String getTest()
 {
   return test;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make some changes in class--

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class ActionClass extends ActionSupport{

```
private String test= "Name from test.java"; 

public String getTest() {
    return test;
}

public String execute() throws Exception {

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

}